# Optimizing switch constructions - how to avoid adding if-clauses

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, refactoring

I am trying to optimize a code that I had to refactor. The code without any optimizations would have some switch statements. If an error occurs inside a switch statement, an error is is returned to the calling method, e.g.:

```
switch(var)
{ 
    case VAL1: 
    //do something... 
    break; 
    case VAL2: 
    //do something else... 
    //... 
    case VAL3: 
    if (...) // there is any case that can cause error 
    { 
         return error1;
    }
    break; 
    case VAL4: 
    if (...) // there is any case that can cause error 
    { 
         return error2;
    }
    break;
    case VAL5: 
    if (...) // there is any case that can cause error 
    { 
         return error1;
    }
    break;
    //and so on... 
    default: 
         break; 
}
```

I am refactoring the code, so I am not returning error in the switch statement, but instead I am marking that there was an error in a variable:

```
int error_type = -1; 

switch(var)
{ 
    case VAL1: 
    //do something... 
    break; 
    case VAL2: 
    //do something else... 
    //... 
    case VAL3: 
    if (...) // there is any case that can cause error 
    { 
         error_type = error1;
    }
    break; 
    case VAL4: 
    if (...) // there is any case that can cause error 
    { 
         error_type = error2;
    }
    break;
    case VAL5: 
    if (...) // there is any case that can cause error 
    { 
         error_type = error1;
    }

    break;
    //and so on... 
    default: 
         break; 
}

if (error_type != -1) 
       return error_type;
```

The problem arises when there is no error because we are adding another if statement which can cause performance issues if the method is called many times per second. I would like to avoid checking the condition every time. Are there any suggestions how I could improve this code? Any switch-refactoring tricks?

//EDIT: I know that this example may look dumb (as the refactoring there wouldn't look very useful) but the actual code that I am refactoring really needs it (belive me) so I am trying not to loose performance in the final code.

Comment: what are the possible values for var?

Comment: Is there any commonality in the if conditions?

Comment: "*I would like to avoid checking the condition every time.*" Which one?

Comment: Can you specify some more about what you're actually trying to optimize out?

Comment: and most important.  Are you sure you need to optimize?  What does the profiler say?

Comment: 1. There are many possible values of var (usually about 20). 
2. There is no commonality in the if conditions. 
3. I would like to avoid checking if there was any error that occured (if (error_type != -1)). 
4. I haven't profiled that code (it is not my task to profile the code). I just would like to refactor the existing code without any drop of performance.

Comment: Assuming var comes from a set of 20 small integers, Thomas' suggestion of using an array to optimize is a good one.  HOWEVER, given the refactoring you have shown I would be astounded if you will see any observable change in performance.  If "many" in :many times per second" is less than a billion then relax and write the cleanest, prettiest, most maintainable code that you can.

Comment: ... the next guy to touch the code (which may be you in the future) will thank you.

Comment: I don't see the gain to replace `return error_code;` by `error_type = error_code;`. (neither for optimization nor readability...)

Comment: What's wrong with the first version  returning error codes directly ?

Comment: If error is exceptional, you may use `exception`.

Comment: Why on earth would you expect this to cause a performance issue? Testing the value of a local variable, in a condition that the CPU will almost certainly predict correctly anyway, could easily turn out to have literally zero impact.

Answer (score 2):

A general rule of thumb is that `switch` statements can be replaced by lookup tables or arrays.  One advantage to the tables is that they can easily be updated at very little performance cost and little modification to the lookup function (engine).

Here are some ideas:

If there is a pattern to the conditional check, put the variables into the table.  Let the engine perform the checking.

Put a function pointer into the table to perform the checking.  If the function pointer is NULL, then there is no checking.

Comment: However, the performance `if (table[x] != NULL) table[x]();` over a `switch(x)` with `if (...)` is probably a "negative" or "zero" - unless you can somehow eliminate complex `if (...)` - however, I'm doubtful. There is indeed a case for using table instead of `switch`, but I don't think this is one of those.

Comment: @MatsPetersson:  Switching to a table lookup may not gain performance in this case, but the OP was also mentioning a maintenance issue of always adding cases to a `switch` statement.  The lookup table is good at reducing maintenance issues.

Comment: To me, that's roughly the same effort...